# How to create JS which transfers data from one local site to another

Tags: javascript, html

situation is this: you enter text to a field in website A and press button, on that button press in website B appears entered text. I have tried using localStorage, but with no luck. any help?

Comment: Please post the code that you have done yet

Comment: You need a server for this; you cannot send data from client to client with in-browser JS. The easiest way is to use node + socket.io (localStorage does exactly what the name implies, otherwise it would be called networkChat)

Comment: Across domains?  You could use sockets with Node.js

Comment: No, just in local

Comment: What makes them different *sites* if they are both local and don't have different domains/hostnames?

Comment: "I have tried using localStorage, but with no luck." — Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: In testing.html

```
function testJS() {
    var b = document.getElementById('name').value,
        url = 'http://path_to_your_html_files/next.html?name=' + encodeURIComponent(b);

    document.location.href = url;
}
```

And in next.html:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var url = document.location.href,
        params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
        data = {}, tmp;
    for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
         tmp = params[i].split('=');
         data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.name;
}
```

Description: javascript can't share data between different pages, and we must to use some solutions, e.g. URL get params (in my code i used this way), cookies, localStorage, etc. Store the name parameter in URL (?name=...) and in next.html parse URL and get all params from prev page.

PS. I'm a non-native English speaker, will you please correct my message, if necessary

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is...
first open Webside B from Webside A

```
var WebsideB = window.open('http://websiteb.com/form/');
```

and find element from that `WebsideB` object

```
WebsideB.document.getElementById('txtName').value= "Ravi Makwana"
```